# Baby Rudin theorem 10.9

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations

The definition we need for the theorem:

The support of a ( real or complex) function $f$ on $R^k$ is the closure of the set of all points $x$ $\in$ $R^k$ at which $f(x)$ $\neq$ $0$.

Suppose $T$ is a $1-1$ $\mathscr C'$(that means continuously differentiable function)- mapping of an open set $E$ $\subset$ $R^k$ into $R^k$ such that $J_T(x)$ $\neq$ $0$ for all $x$ $\in$ $E$. If $f$ is a continuous function on R^k whose support is compact and lies in $T(E)$, then

$\int_{R^k}$ $f(y)$$dy$ = $\int_{R^k}$ $f(T(x))|J_T(x)|dx$ ( mark this equality by ($\star$)).

we recall that $J_T$ is the Jacobian of $T$. The assumption $J_T$$(x)$ $\neq$ $0$ implies, by the inverse function theorem that $T^{-1}$ is continuous on $T(E)$, and this ensures that the integrand on the right of ($\star$) has compact support in $E$.

My question is that:
why is a compactness of the support of $f$ needed? what would be happen if the support of $f$ is n't compact?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: $\int f(y)dy$ exists if $f$ is continuous with compact support. If it is just continuous the integral may not exist.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you explain it why is it so?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I mean why do integral always exist when f is continuous with compact support

Comment: Think of integrals in one dimension, when the function is continuous on $[a,b]$ everything is guaranteed to be defined and finite. When the function is only continuous on $(a,b)$ or is integrated on $(a,\infty)$ we have an improper integral that may diverge. This is just the higher dimensional version (by Heine Borel).

Comment: It is stated nowhere that compact support is needed, but it is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Just like what Kavi Rama Murthy and podiki said, if we just restrict to $k = 1$, then:

$$\int_\mathbb{R} f(y) \, dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) \, dy = \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^R f(y) \, dy$$

where the limiting value $\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^R f(y) \, dy $ could be infinity so that the integral $\int_\mathbb{R} f(y) \, dy$ could not exist in $\mathbb{R}$ (instructive exercise: find a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $\int_\mathbb{R} f(y) \, dy$ does not exist in $\mathbb{R}$).

However, if the support of $f$, denoted $K \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, is compact, then the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} f(y) \, dy$ is finite. Indeed, by continuity, the function $f$ attains a maximum in $K$, i.e., $\sup_{x \in K} f(x) < + \infty$. Since $f(y) = 0$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^k - K$:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} f(y) \, dy = \int_{K} f(y) \, dy + \int_{\mathbb{R}^k - K} f(y) \, dy$$
$$ = \int_{K} f(y) \, dy $$

and since $f(y) \leq \sup_{x \in K} f(x)$ for all $y \in K$, then by a well-known property of the integral:
$$ \leq \int_K \sup_{x \in K} f(x) \, dy = |K| \cdot \sup_{x \in K} f(x) < +\infty$$
where $|K|$ denotes the volume of $K$ which is finite.